# shell/action.xml file not found after oozie completes the w/f, and fails

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am running spark jobs on oozie, but the workflow fails some times with the exception File does not exist: /user/hadoop/oozie-oozi/0096734-161228053611212-oozie-oozi-W/workflowName--shell/action.xml

I am not able to find the root cause, when I rerun the failed step it succeeds. 
We recently added new nodes to the cluster, Can there be any config issue ?
Have anyone faced similar issue ?